# Simple networked computer monitor

Tags: networking, tfs, build, monitoring

My role's responsibilities include monitoring the status of around 300 TFS Build executions. As a result, I have setup an additional computer in an area of our office that runs [Catlight](http://catlight.io).

However, this is only one half of the build executions. I would like to monitor the status of the underlying six Build Controllers for the TFS Build Definitions, as they occasionally become unresponsive and require a reboot.

On the second monitor of this additional computer, what would you recommend for a full-screen, light-weight, simple computer monitoring application that will ascertain whether a networked computer is unresponsive or offline?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Thank you @RonMaupin, I modified the original post in order to clearly state a problem. I'm also attempting to solicit opinionated answers.

Comment: The problem is that questions to solicit opinionated answers are explicitly off-topic here. You probably want to ask this question on [softwarerecs.se], instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for software recommendations.

Comment: @MikeSanders Just for your future reference, questions containing the phrase _"what would you recommend..."_ are very likely to be closed here.

Comment: I voted to delete this post instead. I realize this isn’t software recommendations, but continuing to receive notifications about the same thing (“Don’t post this here!”) makes more work and busyness than I have time for. As a result, if I don’t have the ability to delete my own post, I’ll just remove my notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [monitor the health of your build server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723544(v=vs.120).aspx#server_health), you can check the steps below:

While logged on to the build server, you can confirm Team Foundation Build Service is running, get information about the resources it is consuming, and confirm the general health of the build server.

1. Run Windows Task Manager (Task Manager on Windows 8).
2. On Windows 8, if the **More details** link appears, choose it.
3. Choose the **Process** tab.
4. On versions of Windows other than Windows 8, make sure **Show processes from all users** is selected.
5. On what version of Windows is your build server running?

   - **Windows 8**: Locate the **Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service
     Host** process. It should be located in the **Background processes**
     section, or if your build server is running in interactive mode, in
     the **Apps** section. Observe the CPU, memory, disk, and network
     resources that the process is consuming.
   - **Another Windows version**: Locate the **TFSBuildServiceHost.exe** process.
     Observe the CPU and memory resources that the process is consuming.
6. Use the other tabs in Task Manager to confirm the general health of the build server. For example, you can choose the **Performance** tab to confirm the computer has sufficient processor and memory resources. You can then choose **Resource Monitor** (on Windows 8, **Open Resource Monitor**).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnyStatus](http://www.anystat.us) to monitor both builds and health state of your servers to view the overall status in one place.
Disclaimer: I am the author of AnyStatus